# npm run dev doesn't finish, indicates success

Tags: npm

We have a pipeline that has been working smoothly for weeks running npm commands to build js and css assets for us, but today it started indicating a successful finish when it was only 46% or 47% through the build.  Our pipeline took that as a success and deployed the app, but it didn't have the proper files compiled.

Command run: `npm run dev --verbose`

Output:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev', '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v7.10.1
npm verb run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
npm info lifecycle @~predev: @
npm info lifecycle @~dev: @

> @ dev /var/www/html
> npm run development

npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'development' ]
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v7.10.1
npm verb run-script [ 'predevelopment', 'development', 'postdevelopment' ]
npm info lifecycle @~predevelopment: @
npm info lifecycle @~development: @

> @ development /var/www/html
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

 48% building modules 317/318 modules 1 active ...w/html/resources/assets/sass/app.scssnpm verb lifecycle @~development: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
npm verb lifecycle @~development: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/html/node_modules/.bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/html/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
npm verb lifecycle @~development: CWD: /var/www/html
npm info lifecycle @~postdevelopment: @
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok 
npm verb lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
npm verb lifecycle @~dev: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/html/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
npm verb lifecycle @~dev: CWD: /var/www/html
npm info lifecycle @~postdev: @
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok
```

Any ideas for what could be causing this?  We've had memory issues on smaller machines cause npm to fail, but they never stopped with a successful response before.